# My Firebase database code is not executing

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database, android-ktx

My Firebase database just simply doesn't work in Kotlin, every listener (onComplete, onFailure etc) doesnt work and I don't know why. It'a problem in my other project but i created another one just to make sure and it still doesn't work. Here is my code

```
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Button
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import com.google.firebase.database.ktx.database
import com.google.firebase.ktx.Firebase


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
  override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

      val button : Button = findViewById(R.id.button)

      button.setOnClickListener{
          val database = Firebase.database.reference
          database.child("users").setValue("hello wrolds")
      }




  }
}
```

Here are my dependecies

```
dependencies {

    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.2'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx'
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:26.3.0')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database-ktx:19.6.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to attach a listener to the setValue() operation, to see if something goes wrong?

Comment: Yes I have tried and code inside these listeners is not even executing

Comment: Are you sure you have internet connectivity on the user device?

Comment: What I have checked so far: I run app on my own phone, I made sure i have internet permission in manifest, my firebase is 100% connected because auth works just fine, my rules are both set to true

Comment: Can you attach a screenshot of how your database looks in the console?